# frozen data class with non trivial constructor

Tags: python, constructor, immutability, python-attrs

- I'm trying to define a *frozen data class* with a *non-trivial* constructor
- That is, the constructor needs to "tweak" the input before it initializes the corresponding data member:

```
from attrs import frozen

@frozen(init=False)
class Person:

    name: str

    def __init__(self, raw_name: str) -> None:
        
        if ":" in raw_name:
            self.name = raw_name[raw_name.find(":") + 1:]
        else:
            self.name = raw_name

p = Person("Oren:IshShalom")
```

When I check the [documentation](https://www.attrs.org/en/stable/api.html), I see that

> If a class is frozen, you cannot modify self in **attrs_post_init** or a self-written **init**. You can circumvent that limitation by using object.**setattr**(self, "attribute_name", value).

But I'm not really sure how to do what they suggest

Comment: Instead of writing, for example, `self.name = "Oren"` you would write `setattr(self, "name", "Oren")`

Comment: @FrankYellin it doesn't work, I get: `attr.exceptions.FrozenInstanceError`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Replace

```
self.name = raw_name[raw_name.find(":") + 1:]
```

with

```
object.__setattr__(self, "name", raw_name[raw_name.find(":") + 1:])
```

This works on my end.

Comment: can you add a short explanation what's going on? how come it succeeds?

Comment: All classes in Python are (eventually) inherited from "object". If you look at Person.__bases__ , you will see that your class is inherited from "object" i.e. class Person is exactly similar to the declaration as class Person(object). Now, you can use "setattr" method of "object" to modify attributes of class instance (although you want your class Frozen). This explains it to some degree: https://python-reference.readthedocs.io/en/latest/docs/dunderattr/setattr.html